# How come I can't write to the last byte of the the last block?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd, fdisk

I was doing some tests by writing random patterns of data at a block size of 512 bytes (the size of blocks on my drive) and dd fails at the last block saying that the device ran out of space.

I was doing this tests on a loopback device just to verify that my methods are correct, so I know it's not a bad drive.

`fdisk -l /dev/loop18` shows:

```
Disk /dev/loop18: 24 MiB, 25165824 bytes, 49152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Great. So we have a total of 49152 sectors, each 512 bytes like I mentioned. Writing to every single one works except the last, like I mentioned.

Doing this: `sudo dd if="pattern2.img" of=/dev/loop18 count=1 seek=49152 bs=512` with 'pattern2.img' being a single 512 block written from `/dev/urandom`
Output:

```
dd: error writing '/dev/loop18': No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000167895 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

However... if we do this: `sudo dd if="pattern2.img" of=/dev/loop18 count=1 seek=49152 bs=511` We get no error. So it fails to write at the last byte. How come?

In case you suspect the random image:

```
Disk pattern2.img: 512 B, 512 bytes, 1 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

And a hex dump:

```
0000000 9349 7306 5ffe 5cff 7e01 4596 6a15 e5f6
0000010 c7ff 1a1d 7cc7 861a e907 f0e9 b0fb 8fb4
0000020 1931 5660 0b6b 2101 243e fb58 1c4d 2c55
0000030 376a 062d 308c 647c 9d2d a791 304f aa21
0000040 2831 4d43 9ad8 cefc f880 7077 0948 5966
0000050 e1fa c2ee a43e fcdb 97cf 9479 5bca e6ee
0000060 2a70 eeba 322b ff22 3688 d636 eaea eb03
0000070 c15f 5468 a1cc 172f fba1 8863 a1b0 5d75
0000080 fba5 335c e1ad 1ed4 db26 1607 9822 0c71
0000090 0080 1023 1845 a006 93ca ec13 ddcc 31d1
00000a0 585c f258 e3f9 4b93 14f1 7d21 160b 132f
00000b0 1112 546a baa5 2bcf 2af0 3e9b 8ca0 8ba7
00000c0 424a a730 4799 2d43 bb42 b6d4 0f0f 97d8
00000d0 f06c 6da5 6233 d17c da04 81e7 0533 8dae
00000e0 6d14 96ab f946 4148 5f8c ce78 0f5d ea22
00000f0 f827 4766 8ebb 9a8f 08b7 2355 8fa2 77eb
0000100 c691 5ee9 4f43 3bd6 fc24 9d30 0b42 8f14
0000110 f839 68c1 abd9 cd38 ccc5 1de6 560c 24b3
0000120 810a ec22 270a f882 0de3 9994 6b2b a581
0000130 b5c9 ebcb 2122 28d3 2ad3 a370 c633 3cb4
0000140 90f0 4da5 4a05 03a0 a286 ca44 9404 427a
0000150 18b9 9b10 535a 8b9e f7a2 5018 648b f107
0000160 4dea a1f6 93a1 3e12 d019 e1ff 4347 a9d2
0000170 1942 64fd 303f 3a6b 24af 9bea 78dd 9a16
0000180 e6d7 14d3 896e 8cf7 554f 25e3 02d0 1b46
0000190 6fc1 dc99 7fb1 8620 0fd5 c2f4 042d b9bb
00001a0 366f 8231 388d 0c17 66a3 d6f7 16bd bc62
00001b0 ab86 27a7 a151 e8f3 2e73 371b e123 abf0
00001c0 98c7 d0fd b0d7 6fe6 f4bb d025 b8a8 0bc9
00001d0 5215 50fc 8f8e 9757 0b1f 4dec 788e dd6f
00001e0 64c8 6bf5 e925 1325 02fb d29c f40b 9978
00001f0 99c1 a734 1e7d fd5d a75f d54d ab9b 05a8
0000200
```

That's 512 bytes of data. 0000200 does appear, but it is empty.

So... as a last sanity check: `sudo dd if="/dev/urandom" of=/dev/loop18 count=1 seek=49152 bs=512` which fails in the same way.

How come? What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exactly 49152 512-byte sectors in the `/dev/loop18` block device. With `seek=49152 bs=512` you're skipping them *all*. Before your `dd` starts to write it's already exactly at the end of the output file.

If it was a regular file, then a write starting exactly at the end would append data to it. But `/dev/loop18` is not a regular file, its size is fixed and you cannot expand it this way. Expanding was not your intention anyway.

To write to the last sector you need to skip all *previous* sectors, no more. There are 49151 sectors before the last one, so use `bs=512 seek=49151`.

Your confusion might be caused by an observation (possibly somebody else's observation you have read) that to write to the sector number N you need `seek=N`. The pitfall is in numbering: it starts with 0 (i.e. the initial sector is 0th), thus if there are 49152 sectors then the number of the last one is 49151.

In general remember [`dd` is a cranky tool which is hard to use correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121888/108618). However in this case you have simply skipped to much of the output.

---

With `seek=49152 bs=511` you skip 49152 511-byte chunks of the output, so you're 48 KiB before the end, nowhere near the last byte. Note `bs` specifies both `ibs` and `obs`.

To write any number of bytes to the last 512-byte sector you still need to skip all but one 512-byte sectors of the output, so you need `obs=512 seek=49151`. To write exactly 511 bytes there you need `ibs=511 count=1`. This is a case where it's useful to set `ibs` and `obs` to different values.

Comment: Oh... I see. I should of have figured that out, but because writing 511 bytes worked, I concluded I couldn't write to the last byte. All I was really doing was write a script that writes random patterns of data to each block and then reads them back to verify. Failing to write to the last block confused me so much, so thanks for the clarification. I would of have probably been googling for hours trying to figure out why I couldn't write to the last byte when that wasn't the problem at all. Thank you!